# Negative binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

We throw a coin with success probabilty $p$ and $Y$ is the amount of coin tosses we need untill we have $n$ successes. Now I want to show that $P(Y=n+i)=\begin{pmatrix}n+i-1\\ i \end{pmatrix}p^{n}q^{i}$ whereas $q := (1-p)$ and $n = 0,1,2,...$

There must be some kind of simple answer but somehow I just can't figure it out...

Comment: To my knowledge, $\binom{-n}{i}$ is defined as $0$

Comment: Ok sry I will remove it

Comment: @Vincent ${-n \choose i}$ is defined as $\frac{(-n)(-n - 1)\cdots(-n - i + 1)}{i!}$ in some books

Comment: @jordan178 Do you have learnt generating function before?

Comment: In order for the $n^{th}$ success to occur on the $(n+i)^{th}$ draw we need two things:   $A$. exactly $n-1$ successes amongst the first $n+i-1$ trials and $B$.  A success on the $(n+i)^{th}$ draw.  The probability of $A$ is $\binom {n+i-1}{n-1}p^{n-1}q^{n+i-1-(n-1)}$ and the probability of $B$ is $p$.  Your claim follows quickly.

Comment: Yes the basics, feel free to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{Y=n+i\}$ is the event that among $n+i-1$ experiments there were $i$ failures, and secondly also that the $n+i$-th experiment was a success.

There are $\binom{n+i-1}{i}$ ways of selecting $i$ experiments out of $n+i-1$.

Each of these selections goes along with a probability of $p^{n-1}q^i$ of occurring.

The  $n+i$-th experiment has probability $p$ to succeed.

Multiplication of these factors gives: $$P(Y=n+i)=\binom{n+i-1}{i}p^nq^i$$

Comment: I love this solution! Thanks a lot! One more question: How can I use this to show that $X_1 + X_2 + .. + X_n$ of independant, geometric distributed random variables is negativ binomial distributed?

Comment: You can use induction. Assume that $S_n:=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ indeed has this distribution with parameters $n,p$ and - based on that - prove that $S_n+X_{n+1}$ will have it too with parameters $n+1,p$.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference as an alternative solution, though more complex.

---

Let $X$ be the number of coin tosses until we get a success. Then
$$
\Pr(X = i) = q^{i-1}p
$$
The corresponding generating function is
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty q^{i-1}p\cdot x^i = \frac{p}{q}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^\infty (qx)^i = \frac{p}{q} \cdot \frac{qx}{1-qx}=\frac{px}{1-qx}
$$
Now $Y = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$, where $X_i$ has the same distribution as $X$. Hence, the generating function for $Y$ is
$$
g(x) = f(x)^n = (\frac{px}{1-qx})^n
$$
Because
$$
(\frac{1}{1-qx})^n = (1 + (-qx))^{-n} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty {-n \choose i}(-qx)^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(n+i-1)\cdots(n+1)(n)}{i!}(qx)^i
$$
where ${-n \choose i} = \frac{(-n)(-n-1)\cdots(-n-i+1)}{i!}$, we thus have
$$
g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(n+i-1)\cdots(n+1)(n)}{i!}p^nq^ix^{i+n} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty {n + i - 1\choose i}p^nq^ix^{i+n}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\Pr(Y = n + i) = {n + i - 1 \choose i}p^nq^i
$$

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it! One more question though: How can I use this to show that X_1 + X_2 + .. + X_n of independant, geometric distributed random variables is negativ binomial distributed?